# why i get blank uploaded file to ftp from powershell

Tags: powershell

i get tutorial this
[FTP upload](http://www.freekb.net/Article?id=416)

```
#Unique Variables
$FTPServer = "ftp://example.com/"
$FTPUsername = "username"
$FTPPassword = "password" 
$LocalDirectory = "C:\temp\" 
$FileToUpload = "example.txt"

#Connect to the FTP Server
$ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::create("$FTPServer/$FileToUpload")
$ftp.Credentials =  New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($FTPUsername,$FTPPassword)

#Upload file to FTP Server
$ftp.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile

#Verify the file was uploaded
$ftp.GetResponse()
```

but on my ftp i get only blank file, why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You don't seem to upload the file (the actual bytes) at all.. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867385/upload-files-with-ftp-using-powershell)

Comment: this how it looks  on ftp side, its not clear text, just bunch of these:
" H^@D^@D^@ ^@C^@a^@p^@a^@c^@i^@t^@y^@:^@ ^@2^@2^@3^@.^@0^@5^@G^@B^@
^@
^@D^@i^@s^@k^@ ^@T^@y^@p^@e^@:^@ ^@
^@
^@
^@
^@W^@D^@C^@ ^@W^@D^@1^@0^@P^@U^@R^@X^@-
"